# Why does elasticsearch reports swapping when swapping is disabled?

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

When trying to [disable JVM swapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html) I disabled paging on a Windows machine and rebooted:

[image]

When looking at the cluster health via [Elastic HQ](http://www.elastichq.org/), I see that the JVM swaps very much anyway:

[image]

Why is it so? Is the reading not accurate or is swap occuring despite the paging being 0 MB?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird, but any way you can disable the swapping behaviour by enabling ]mlockall.

> mlockall will try to lock the process address space into RAM, preventing
>   any Elasticsearch memory from being swapped out. This can be done, by
>   adding this line to the config/elasticsearch.yml file:

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Elastic HQ uses the following method to get the swap value:

```
formula:"stats.os.swap.used_in_bytes / 1024 / 1024"
```

IIRC, ES uses *sigar* to offer "stats.os.swap.used_in_bytes" and *sigar* uses "Paging Files" performance counter to finally get the number of bytes of paging files used by the ES.

You can double check this counter value by issuing

```
Get-Counter '\Paging Files\% Usage'
```

in windows power shell.